# Source control for images with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 attribute for my images as below

```
 data-web-src
 data-tablet-src
 data-mobil-src
```

So if `data-tablet-src` or `data-mobil-src` is undefined or empty then hide current image. I couldn't achieve so far.

```js
   function noLazyImages(e) {
    $(e + '.lazy_res').attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
        var elData = $(this).data(),
            winWidth = $(window).width();
        if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
            if (elData['tabletSrc']) {
                return elData['tabletSrc'];
            }
        } else if (winWidth < 480) {
            if (elData['mobilSrc']) {
                return elData['mobilSrc'];
            }
        }
        return elData['webSrc'];
    });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    noLazyImages("body img");
});
noLazyImages("body img");
```

```css
img{
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/b1e10f433e404191bb78123f5188dc56.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/bqNoZz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.attr` I would use `.each` as you can then hide the image if the condition is not met:

```js
function noLazyImages(e) {
  $(e + '.lazy_res').each(function() {
    var image = $(this),
      elData = image.data(),
      winWidth = $(window).width();
      
    if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
 
      // tablet screen width
      if (elData['tabletSrc']) {
        image.attr('src', elData['tabletSrc']).show();   // show image if exists or hide
      } else {
        image.hide();
      }
    } else if (winWidth < 480) {
      // mobile screen width
      if (elData['mobilSrc']) {
        image.attr('src', elData['mobilSrc']).show();  // show image if exists or hide
      } else {
        image.hide();
      }
    } else {

      // all other screen widths
      if (elData['webSrc']) {
        image.attr('src', elData['webSrc']).show();  // need to add .show() here in case image was hidden by a different screen size
      } else {
        image.hide();
      }
    }
  })
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  noLazyImages("body img");
});
noLazyImages("body img");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/b1e10f433e404191bb78123f5188dc56.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"
/>
```

[Fiddle so you can adjust the frame size and see it working](https://jsfiddle.net/cno3odra/1)

One other thing I would add is that lazy loaded images are meant to have a default placeholder image url for before the js loads and the image scrolls into view

Comment: great so I tried then I don't fill data-mobil-src any value it works but after resize to tablet or web then I my tablet and web image doesn't appear anymore

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS JS CODE

```
function noLazyImages(e) {
  $(e + '.lazy_res').each(function(id, elm) {

    if (!$(elm).data()['mobilSrc'] || !$(elm).data()['tabletSrc'])     {
      $(this).hide();
    }

    $(elm).attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
      var elData = $(elm).data(),
        winWidth = $(window).width();
      if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
        if (elData['tabletSrc']) {
          return elData['tabletSrc'];
        }
      } else if (winWidth < 480) {
        if (elData['mobilSrc']) {
          return elData['mobilSrc'];
        }
      }
      return elData['webSrc'];
    });

  });
}
```

```js
function noLazyImages(e) {
  $(e + '.lazy_res').each(function(id, elm) {

    if (!$(elm).data()['mobilSrc'] || !$(elm).data()['tabletSrc'])     {
      $(this).hide();
    }
    
    $(elm).attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
      var elData = $(elm).data(),
        winWidth = $(window).width();
      if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
        if (elData['tabletSrc']) {
          return elData['tabletSrc'];
        }
      } else if (winWidth < 480) {
        if (elData['mobilSrc']) {
          return elData['mobilSrc'];
        }
      }
      return elData['webSrc'];
    });

  });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  noLazyImages("body img");
});
noLazyImages("body img");
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/b1e10f433e404191bb78123f5188dc56.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"
/>

<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to hide the image if `data-tablet-src` or `data-mobil-src` are `undefined` or empty you just need to use a test:

```
if(!elData['tabletSrc'] || elData['tabletSrc'] == '' || !elData['mobilSrc'] || elData['mobilSrc'] == ''){
     $(this).hide();
     return "";
}
```

**Demo:**

Here's a working Demo snippet with two images example.

```js
function noLazyImages(e) {
    $(e + '.lazy_res').attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
        var elData = $(this).data(),
            winWidth = $(window).width();
            if(!elData['tabletSrc'] || elData['tabletSrc'] == '' || !elData['mobilSrc'] || elData['mobilSrc'] == ''){
            $(this).hide();
            return "";
           }
        if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
            if (elData['tabletSrc']) {
                return elData['tabletSrc'];
            }
        } else if (winWidth < 480) {
            if (elData['mobilSrc']) {
                return elData['mobilSrc'];
            }
        }
        return elData['webSrc'];
    });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    noLazyImages("body img");
});
noLazyImages("body img");
```

```css
img{
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/b1e10f433e404191bb78123f5188dc56.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/>

<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can see the second image without `data-tablet-src` and `data-mobil-src` is empty is hidden.

Comment: thank you but it didn't work: https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/MogKrG only my data-mobil-src is empty in this example

Comment: @ani_css Do you need it to be both empty or only one of them? There's a difference; in that case you need : `if((!elData['tabletSrc'] || elData['tabletSrc'] == '') && (!elData['mobilSrc'] || elData['mobilSrc'] == '')`

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`filter()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZut-jy5zUAhXHpI8KHdjtC7sQFgg1MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffilter%2F&usg=AFQjCNGIjOndwopfFySn6E1gc8znkMPSPw&sig2=Bz05junsNxtwoMouGSAu-Q) function of jquery and find the attribute of `data-mobil-src` && `data-tablet-src` is  empty ,null.undefined using `if(!)`.its return the false attribute element.then apply the `hide()`

See my below snippet I was added two image `first` one is true `second` one is false *(is not visible)*

```js
$('.lazy_res').filter(function(){
return !$(this).attr('data-mobil-src').trim() && !$(this).attr('data-tablet-src').trim()
}).hide()

function noLazyImages(e) {
    $(e + '.lazy_res').attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
        var elData = $(this).data(),
            winWidth = $(window).width();
        if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
            if (elData['tabletSrc']) {
                return elData['tabletSrc'];
            }
        } else if (winWidth < 480) {
            if (elData['mobilSrc']) {
                return elData['mobilSrc'];
            }
        }
        return elData['webSrc'];
    });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    noLazyImages("body img");
});
noLazyImages("body img");
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/b1e10f433e404191bb78123f5188dc56.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"
/>
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="" data-tablet-src=""
/>
```

Comment: @ani_css Its working .you are missing `document.ready` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgLyxa .Stackoverflow snippet default have `document.ready`